# MongoDB aggregation stages - $setWindowFields vs $group vs. $bucket?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

This is a general question regarding two different stages in the MongoDB aggregation framework, `$group` and `$bucket`. I'm starting to build more complex aggregations, but I'm unsure of when to use `$group` vs `$bucket` vs `$setWindowFields`.

For example, I made a view of pre-aggregated stats (based on this presentation [Materialized Pre-Aggregations for Exploratory Analytics Queries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPj7oBGaTZI&list=PL4RCxklHWZ9tKWSS21BmtFxOs51f-l1o9&index=29).

```
{
  "_id": {
    "campaign": "63e153491c36152778641364",
    "bot": "63f00a6fc2c3c07f02673d42",
    "render-status": "done",
    "stream-status": "pending",
    "processor": "63f00a6fc2c3c07f02673d42"
  },
  "total": 5,
  "last_updated": {
    "$date": "2023-03-14T15:11:26.000Z"
  }
}
```

I plan to use this aggregation for a dashboard and need to break out these stats by `render-status`, `stream.status`, `bot` and `processor` - basically, a `group` stage for each of these.

In the past, I've used the `$facet` stage with separate `$group` stages for each field to accomplish this. However, I've never used `$bucket` or `$setWindowFields`, but from the docs they look like they might also work for this use case.

Generally, do you use `$group` when you are grouping by distinct values on a field and `$bucket` when you're grouping by time or date values? When would you use `$setWindowFields`? Is it a matter of preference, or are there performance implications?

Thank you kindly.